# Wordpress - Admin not found

Tags: wordpress

Have a strange error that has recently popped up that I am struggling to resolve.

I have a wordpress install using the sub domain method:

www.example.com/wordpress

in my root directory I have .htaccess:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

And my index file:

```
<?php
define('WP_USE_THEMES', true);

/** Loads the WordPress Environment and Template */
require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/wordpress/wp-blog-header.php' );
```

home is set to: www.example.com
url is set to: www.example.com/wordpress

When I try and access the admin at: www.example.com/wordpress/wp-admin I get the error: **Sorry, but the page you are looking for could not be found.**

This is not a new install of Wordpress and this issue only recently happened after an auto update.

How do I go about bug testing this?

Comment: Try to login with : www.example.com/wordpress/wp-login.php

Comment: I did try, unfortunately it does not work.

Comment: Paste your URL here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fix for this was relatively simple. After checking the apache logs I noticed the following error each time I attempted to access the admin URL:

> SoftException in Application.cpp:256: File
>   "/home/example/public_html/wordpress/wp-login.php" is writeable by
>   group

The permissions for this file were set to: 644 which in theory should work. I read on the Wordpress Codex that permissions should either be 644 or 640:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_File_Permissions

I changed the wp-login.php file to 640 and my problem was resolved.

I think this errors came about not due to a wordpress update but rather a server update. This is likely a common problem for Cpanel managed servers.

Comment: Alternatively, check the permissions for the "wp-admin" folder as well. In my situation, this was the culprit... it had 775 for whatever reason (left over from local development), and my fix was changing it to 755... meanwhile my wp-login.php already had the official recommended settings.

Answer (score 2):

You're using a sub*directory* installation (rather than a sub*domain* installation); as such, your `.htaccess` file doesn't belong in the root directory - it should be in your `/wordpress/` directory, along with the rest of your installation.

In addition, your `.htaccess` needs to be edited to account for the fact that it resides in a subdirectory:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wordpress/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wordpress/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

You should also remove the `wordpress/` part from your `index.php` file. The PHP magic constant `__FILE__` essentially means 'relative to this file', so if your `index.php` file is in `/wordpress/`, it's effectively saying 'look in /wordpress/wordpress/ for wp-blog-header.php`.

So amend that line in your `index.php` file to this:

```
require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/wp-blog-header.php' );
```

...and everything should work as expected.

Comment: I followed this installation form the codex: https://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory Checking the apache logs I see this error: File .. wordpress/wp-login.php" is writeable by group

Comment: @HappyCoder Huh. So, I guess I've never read those - I've done dozens of subdirectory installations and never once done it 'their' way (hence the answer above) and it's always worked as expected. In that case, I guess you'll have to change permissions (chmod) for `wp-login.php`. Depending on what program you use, I'd recommend changing the file permissions to 644. Note that you may have to do this for other files too - keep an eye on what your error logs say.

Comment: I did try your way to see if it would help, but as I discovered it was nothing to do with the method, but rather to do with the server side permissions. We learn every day!